# How should I inject the code from my app into collection's product grid for each item in shopify

Tags: shopify, themes

I have been creating a shopify wishlist app, but I can't seem to get around adding the wishlist icon onto grid item on collections template. I need to inject it programmatically because I want the app compatible to any shopify theme, not restricted to one html structure.

I have tried adding it via javascript, but in that way we don't have the product id, variant id, or product handle information to retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

Your wishlist is likely best executed using the Theme App Extension pattern. With that, your wishlist become something (A section block) that any merchant can install in their theme and customize, with all the good logic your Wishlist needs. It's not a hard pattern to follow.

Comment: I am already adding the app block and extension to add the functionality of wishlist, but your answer still doesn't answer my question. 
Its impossible for an app block /section to embed inside each product grid on collection page, and there's no way you can add the code in any theme's html structure, you don't know what classes they use, or elements,

Comment: I would not be so sure, as to say impossible. It's a block. Modern themes allow them to be drag and drop for merchants. You have a little bit of work figuring out where. A theme grid might not be the best place for something not part of the grid, but before/after the grid is probably fine and easy.

Comment: I already know that the block can be injected before and after the grids, and latest themes might also enable to customize the grid item's as blocks, 
But my original question is about the app to make it compatible with previous themes, which don't have the sections/block functionality on collections template. How should we inject the code there?

Comment: You get to do what everyone has done since day 1. You publish basic HTML your merchant customers can copy and paste, and you give them instructions on how and where to copy and paste that code. Fun fun fun!